# jQuery Hotkeys "Tab" on Chrome will still insert \t character, even after return false

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Suppose I have 2 code like below, 1 uses `alert()` 1 doesn't. I found that in chrome, the 1 using `alert()` will insert a tab character `\t` into the textarea.

```
$(function() {
  $("textarea").bind("keydown", "tab", function() {
    alert("something");
    return false;
  }); 
  $("textarea").bind("keydown", "shift+tab", function() {
    this.value = "don't alert()";
    return false;
  }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tu6vF/4/

Why is this happening? and how can I prevent this behaviour (adding of the tab character after return false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use this code before "return false"

```
if(jQuery.browser.msie) {
    event.cancelBubble = true;
} else {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

You need to add the parameter event in each binding :

```
function(event) { ... }
```